# Handle badarg in Erlang

Tags: json, list, binary, erlang, kazoo

I am very new to the Erlang and I am getting badarg error when I try to convert binary to string as shown below.

```
Prefix = binary:bin_to_list(wh_json:get_ne_value(<<"prefix">>, Patterns)),
```

where `Patterns` are:

```
Pattern1--> {[{<<"prefix">>,<<>>},{<<"callerId">>,<<"1001">>},{<<"cid_regex">>,<<"^\\+?1001">>}]}

Pattern2--> {[{<<"prefix">>,<<"12">>},{<<"callerId">>,<<"1001">>},{<<"cid_regex">>,<<"^\\+?1001">>}]}
```

for `Pattern2` it works fine but for `Pattern1` I am getting this error because prefix does not have any value in `Pattern1`.

So, can any one tell me how I can handle this situation where prefix value can be `null` or any value, it should work for both the conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether `wh_json:get_ne_value` returns `undefined` before calling `binary:bin_to_list`:

```
Prefix =
    case wh_json:get_ne_value(<<"prefix">>, Patterns) of
        undefined ->
            prefix_not_found;
        BinaryPrefix when is_binary(BinaryPrefix) ->
            binary:bin_to_list(BinaryPrefix)
    end
```