# Erlang "badarg", Not sure how to handle

Tags: erlang

Before I start, I have already checked out [Handle badarg in Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199963/handle-badarg-in-erlang)
But I am still not successful in my undefined checks so I removed them.

I am building a dummy bank process and when a client does a balance query check to the bank process, the program exits, saying:

```
Error in process <0.373.0> with exit value:
{badarg,[{project4,client,3,
                   [{file,"/Users/owner/Desktop/bank.erl"},
                    {line,27}]}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 26-Oct-2016::13:34:57 ===
Error in process <0.379.0> with exit value:
{badarg,[{project4,client,3,
                   [{file,"/Users/owner/Desktop/bank.erl"},
                    {line,27}]}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 26-Oct-2016::13:34:57 ===
Error in process <0.375.0> with exit value:
{badarg,[{project4,client,3,
                   [{file,"/Users/owner/Desktop/bank.erl"},
                    {line,27}]}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 26-Oct-2016::13:34:58 ===
Error in process <0.377.0> with exit value:
{badarg,[{project4,client,3,
                   [{file,"/Users/owner/Desktop/bank.erl"},
                    {line,27}]}]}
<0.378.0> Balance request: 54> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 26-Oct-2016::13:34:58 ===
Error in process <0.378.0> with exit value:
{badarg,[{project4,client,3,
                   [{file,"/Users/owner/Desktop/bank.erl"},
                    {line,39}]}]}
<0.372.0> Balance request: 54> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 26-Oct-2016::13:34:58 ===
Error in process <0.372.0> with exit value:
{badarg,[{project4,client,3,
                   [{file,"/Users/owner/Desktop/bank.erl"},
                    {line,39}]}]}
```

The code for the simulation is here:

```
-module(bankSim).
-export([start/0, negativeOrPositive/0, sleep/1, generate_rand_int_list/3, generate_rand/2, client/3, clientSpawn/2, bank/2]).

negativeOrPositive() -> 
    M = rand:uniform(),
    if
        M =< 0.5 -> 
            1;
        true -> 
            -1
    end.

sleep(T) ->
    receive
        after T -> ok
    end.

generate_rand_int_list(N,StartVal,Lim) ->
    lists:map(fun (_) -> (rand:uniform(Lim-StartVal) + StartVal)* negativeOrPositive() end, lists:seq(1,N)).

generate_rand(StartVal, Lim) ->
    rand:uniform(Lim-StartVal) + StartVal.

client([], _ , BankID) ->
    BankID ! {goodbye};
client([H|T], Count, BankID) ->
    BankID ! {transaction, self(), H},
    receive
        {Amount, Balance, Success} ->
            io:format("Client: ~w, Amount requested: ~w, Bank Balance: ~w, Transaction successful ~w ~n",[self(), Amount, Balance, Success]);
        { X } ->
            io:format("The balance is ~w ~n", [X])
    end,    
    sleep(generate_rand(500, 1500)),
    Mod = Count rem 5,
    if 
        Mod == 0 -> 
            io:format("~w Balance request: ",[ self() ]),
            BankID! {balance, self()};
        true -> 
            ok
    end,
    client(T, Count + 1, BankID).

clientSpawn(0, _) ->
        io:format("Finished spawning clients ~n",[]);
clientSpawn(N, BankID) -> 
        spawn(bankSim, client, [ generate_rand_int_list( generate_rand(10, 20), 0, 100) , 1, BankID] ),
        clientSpawn(N-1, BankID).


bank(Balance, 0) ->
    io:format("Banking simulation ended with a final balance of ~w ~n", [Balance]),
    io:format("simulation completed ~n", []);
bank(Balance, NumClients) ->
    receive
        {balance, Client} ->
            Client ! {Balance};
        {transaction, Client, Amount} ->
            NewBalance = Balance + Amount,
            if 
                NewBalance =< 0 ->
                    Client ! {Amount, NewBalance, no},
                    bank(Balance, NumClients);
                NewBalance > 0 ->
                    Client ! {Amount, NewBalance, yes},
                    bank(NewBalance, NumClients);
                true -> 
                    io:format("This will never be printed")
            end;
        goodbye ->
            NewNumClients = NumClients - 1,
            bank(Balance, NewNumClients)
    end.


start()->
    N = generate_rand(2,10),
    register(bank ,spawn(bankSim, bank, [generate_rand(2000,3000), N])),
    clientSpawn(N,bank).
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you forgot the recursive call for `{balance, Client}` message? (Line 57-58.)

Comment: That seemed to have worked, I've been staring at it so long I've probably kept glossing over such a simple mistake.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Erlang documentation will tell you that `badarg` means ["The argument is of wrong data type, or is otherwise badly formed."](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/errors.html#id86936) Which I never find very elucidating.

Dogbert points out that you missed a recursive call to `bank/2` in one of your cases. This is the source of your `badarg`s -- but why?

I always think of `badarg` as meaning "bad argument sent to a BIF". If you're calling a regular Erlang function, you'll get a `function_clause` error, meaning that there was no function clause that matched your data.

The error message you're getting lists two different line numbers. One is for the line

```
BankID ! {transaction, self(), H},
```

and the other for

```
BankID! {balance, self()};
```

The argument that is bad is `BankID`. The reason that it's bad is because it is an atom, `bank`. In your `start/0` function, you spawn a new bank process and then register the PID of that process as `bank`. Then in your client, you're sending messages to the `bank` atom and having Erlang resolve that to the registered PID.

It works for a while, but when you hit the missing-recusion case your `bank` process terminates. Now there's nobody registered behind the `bank` atom, and the send operator blows up because it can't send to a defunct name.

If you changed you code to

```
Bank = spawn(bankSim, bank, [generate_rand(2000,3000), N]),
clientSpawn(N, Bank).
```

then you would not get the `badarg`, because it's not an error to send messages to a PID where nobody's running. You might enjoy trying that without fixing the `bank` loop and seeing what happens.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct because of your explanation and the solution you offered is correct as well. Thank you for your insight!

Comment: @Nathaniel, a remark about the sentence `I always think of badarg as meaning "bad argument sent to a BIF"`, `To ! Msg` is a call to the operator `send` which uses 2 parameters, although the Erlang creators chose an operator syntax to send messages, there is not much difference compare to `global:send(To,Msg)` syntax. very neat answer.

Comment: You will also find that in some of the standard libraries you will also get a `badarg` error if the arguments are wrong. This is explicitly done as it is definitely more informative than a `function_clause` error, or `case_clause`, or some other error that may occur because of a bad argument.